# Pyscripter: Disable error windows popup

Tags: python, pyscripter

I am using PyScripter version 2.5.3.0 X86.

When I run a python script which has an error (ValueError), an error window popups with a annoying beep sound. 
Is it possible to disable this error window with the sound?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disable the system sounds in the taskbar if working in windows. This only removes the beep however.